# Converting HTML to markdown in jodit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jodit

In the below link i'm using jodit editor with react. On changing the text it returns html with the styles we have selected.On typing, below you can  see the value that it returns. I need some help in printing them in markdown language, is it possible to do in it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-haze-yfbug

Tried converting the returned html to markdown using https://www.npmjs.com/package/turndown,

For example  `<p><span style="font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">ME typing</span></p>`
while trying the convert the above using turndown service it just returns `ME typing` styles are not present.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

just use

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: value}}></div>`.

it should load it in the right way

Comment: I want to converted that html to markdown language. dangerouslySetInnerHTML just gives the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import dompurify from 'dompurify';
import { marked } from 'marked';

marked.setOptions({
    breaks: true,
    gfm: true,
    pedantic: false,
    renderer: new marked.Renderer(),
    smartLists: false,
    smartypants: false,
    xhtml: false,
});

export const convertMarkedDownToHtml = (content: string): string => {
    const parsedHTML = dompurify.sanitize(marked.parse(content));
    return parsedHTML;
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).